# AngularJs: Nested state not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I am trying to implement nested states in my project but they are not working as expected.

Though View template and js calls are made and loading in the back but the screen does not change in other words nested screen does not show.

http://{domain}/#/app/store/users/1/new

Below is code snippet of my work

```
.state('app.store.users', {
    url: '/users/:storeid',
    params: { storeid: '1' },
    templateUrl: 'store/users',
    controller: 'UsersController',
    require: ['users', 'datatables'],
    data: {
    displayName: 'Store Users'
    }
})
.state('app.store.users.new', {
    url: '/new',
    templateUrl: 'store/newuser',
    controller: 'NewUserController',
    require: ['newuser'],
    data: {
    displayName: 'New User'
    }
})
;
```

http://{domain}/#/app/store/users/1/new

Considering above url, displaying **Users** not **NewUser**.

thanks in advance!!

Comment: why your url is like this /app/store/users ... ? from where comes app/store ?

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: @ZeRubeus there are two parent states above them 'app' and 'app.store' sequentially have url '/app' and 'app/store'. till /users things are working fine.

Comment: @RahulArora no error in console

Comment: have you tried to you abstract ? or parent ?

Comment: @ZeRubeus i cannot do 'abstract' as I '/users' is also a separate view and perhaps 'users.new' (parent.child) works the same way as 'parent'

Comment: Have u added ui-view to app.store.users?

Comment: @RahulArora I do not understand by ui-view but previously they (users and new) were at the same level ('/store/users' and '/store/new') then they were working fine but now I need to change them as above to implement 'breadcrumbs'. thanks!

Comment: @ankIT: please check my answer below and let me know if it helps

Comment: @RahulArora sorry for my explanation but I want them as two separate screens but nested url as mentioned above.

'http://{domain}/#/app/store/users/1' (parent screen) and 'http://{domain}/#/app/store/users/1/new' (next or child screen)

Comment: @ankIT please check my edit in the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118744/discussion-between-ankit-and-rahul-arora).

Comment: @RahulArora in plunker 'ui-view' attribute is given a value (main) but in my case that is empty can you suggest how can I make it work with empty 'ui-view'?

Comment: It is given a value "main" because in the state the controller and the template might be passed in an object main, in your case its not required

Comment: @RahulArora issue has been fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `ui-view` in the parent view so that, it knows that there is a child view attached to it.

Basically include

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

OR

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

in the partial of **app.store.users** state, at the place where you want to load the HTML for child state (**app.store.users.new**)

This is how ui-router works.

Check this plunker to understand it better:
http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview

**EDIT:**

If you want them as two separate screens they should not be in a parent-child relationship. They should be two separate states where in URL can still be nested. Just change your state names to be independent of each other.

Something like this will work:

```
.state('app.store.users', {
    url: '/users/:storeid',
    params: { storeid: '1' },
    templateUrl: 'store/users',
    controller: 'UsersController',
    require: ['users', 'datatables'],
    data: {
    displayName: 'Store Users'
    }
})
.state('app.store.newusers', {
    url: '/users/:storeid/new',
    params: { storeid: '1' }, //you still have to pass params to it
    templateUrl: 'store/newuser',
    controller: 'NewUserController',
    require: ['newuser'],
    data: {
    displayName: 'New User'
    }
});
```